# Отправка - получение и получение - отправка данных через socket

Tags: java, spring, сокет

Добрый день

**Задача:** отправить с клиента объект байтами, получить на сервере и отправить ответ.

**Проблема:** Клиент отправляет, сервер получает но не обрабатывает и не отправляет обратно ответ. "зависает" в ожидании...

Если с сервера убрать отправку ответа для клиента и просто преобразовать побайтово обратно объект, все работает

Может кто-то сталкивался... в чем проблема?

*Сервер*

```
public void receiveData() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(settingsConnection.getPort());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("port " + serverSocket.toString());
    System.out.println("Wait...");
    System.out.println("");

    Socket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("socket " + socket.toString());

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;

        try {
            inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);

        Object o;

        while (true) {

            byte[] result = IOUtils.readFully(dataInputStream, -1, false);
            byte[] bytes = encryption.description(result);
            o = serializer.deserialize(bytes);

            Today today = (Today) o;
            System.out.println("input stream " + today.getVal());

            Today today1 = new Today();
            today1.setVal(1313);

                dataOutputStream.write(serializer.serialize(today1));
                dataOutputStream.flush();
                System.out.println("output stream sent");

            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
            socket.close();
            serverSocket.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

*Клиент*

```
 public void sendTo(Object o) {

    InetAddress ipAddress = null;
    try {
        ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(client.getAddressServer());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Socket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = new Socket(ipAddress, client.getPortServer());
        System.out.println("socket " + socket.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    InputStream inputStream = null;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        if (socket != null) {
            inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);

    int count = 0;

    while (true) {
        try {
            dataOutputStream.write(encryption.encription(serialize((Serializable) o)));
            outputStream.flush();
            System.out.println("sent data to server");


            byte[] result = IOUtils.readFully(dataInputStream, -1, false);
            byte[] bytes = encryption.decription(result);
            Object o1 = deserialize(bytes);

            Today today = (Today) o1;
            System.out.println("input stream " + today.getVal());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

*Вывод*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SocketTestTwoApplication.class, args);
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    Today today = new Today();
    today.setVal(50011);

    clientService.sendTo(today);
    System.out.println("today " + today.getVal());

}
```

зы... объекты Today для тестовых целей

Зараннее спасибо